# How are Person Accounts billed in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

I am syncing Person Accounts (effectively Accounts and Contact objects) from my Salesforce CRM to Marketing Cloud. As syncronised objects are also billed by Marketing Cloud, can anyone confirm how this works when we use Person Accounts as they effectively create a duplicate record in both Account and Contact objects?

The Marketing Cloud [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm) on Contact Counts isn't particularly clear on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are billed for "Sendable Objects" - effectively Contacts, Leads and Users. Accounts are just data and don't count towards your contact counts for billing purposes.